# jQuery hide element at certain point from top of page not browser?

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollto

I need to control an element from a set point from the top of the page until another set point. But only from within the page not the browser window as currently i have..

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
      if($(this).scrollTop() > 600) $('#plane').fadeOut('slow');
      if($(this).scrollTop() < 600) $('#plane').fadeIn('slow');
    });
```

This works perfectly if the page loads at the top, but sometimes the page might link to another point and the above script thinks its the top of the browser thus showing the #plane when it shouldn't really..

So ideally the top of the site, not the top of the browser window...

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check the `scrollTop` value on load of the page. Try this:

```
function checkScrollPosition() {
    $(window).scrollTop() > 600 ? $('#plane').fadeOut('slow') : $('#plane').fadeIn('slow');
});

$(window).scroll(checkScrollPosition); // check on scroll
checkScrollPosition(); // check on load
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(window).scroll(checkscroll);  


      function checkscroll(){
          var top = $(window).scrollTop();
          if(top > 600){
            $('#plane').fadeOut('slow');
          }else{
            $('#plane').fadeIn('slow');
          }
      }

   checkscroll();
```